# If I see an valuable question that's old and off-topic on one site, should I re-ask it on the correct site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, migration, asking-questions, off-topic

I just came across an interesting question, [What is the etymology of 'slug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230846/what-is-the-etymology-of-slug) (a 'slug' being the sequence of characters in URLs like "what-is-the-etymology-of-slug"), and it's fairly well-answered, but it's on Stack Overflow and thus off-topic.

It's a perfectly suitable question for English.SE though. I've now come to terms with the 60-day limit on migrations, but regardless, it's a good question for English.SE. Should I ask the same question on English.SE given I'm interested about it? The answer, albeit informative, could certainly be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question. But, cross-posting across the network is generally discouraged in order to both avoid confusion and unnecessary off-topic duplicates.

So instead, flag it for moderator's attention and explain clearly about why you think it's on-topic on that particular site. And I'm sure, the mods would be happy to initiate a migration process if they think it's appropriate to do so!

Comment: I've previously flagged an old question for migration that was off-topic, but perfectly on-topic for another site, but that was declined by a mod. Plenty discussions on the Meta sites to support that refusal, and I'm certainly not wanting to build up a horde of flag declines. So not sure I'm game for that.

Comment: @andrewb But, the mods are the best ones to decide on the flag. In case, you are not sure about the flag, then raise a meta discussion regarding the issue :)

Comment: Alright cool, I'll see if I can raise a meta discussion then

Comment: If it is over the 60 day limit, mods will not be able to migrate it anyway...